# Residue theorem to find $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^3}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

When giving an example of applications of the residue theorem, my professor wrote the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^3}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z=\oint_\Gamma\frac{z^3}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i \mathrm{Res}(f,i)$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the (counterclockwise) contour made up by taking the limit $R\to\infty$ of the two pieces $[-R,R]$ and a semicircle parameterized by $Re^{i\theta}$, for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$. My professor claims that the integral over the semicircle vanishes as $R\to\infty$ by Jordan's Lemma. It seems to me, naively, that since the integrand scales as $R^2$ and the length of the semicircular arc scales as $R$, the integral over the semicircle should scale as $R^3$, and hence would not vanish. This leads me to also to conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^3}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z$ might not converge.

Why does the integral over the semicircle of $\frac{z^3}{z-i}$ vanish?

Comment: You're right, the integral over the semicircle does not vanish in the limit—indeed the original function is definitely not integrable on $(-\infty,\infty)$ by the same observation that the integrand grows like $z^2$ on both ends.

Comment: @GregMartin My professor has replied that the integral over the semicircular contour vanishes by Jordan's lemma. I can't see how to apply Jordan's lemma here. Does it apply, and if so, how?

Comment: The integral you are considering is divergent. You cannot evaluate it by any means. Tell your professor that the improper integral does not converge. There is nothing to solve here.

Comment: I don't believe Jordan's lemma can be applied (there is no factor of the form $e^{iaz}$ with $a>0$), and even if it were applied it wouldn't imply that the integral over the contour vanishes. It sounds like your professor is wrong, but are you 100% sure that you've copied the integrand correctly?